# Can not enter characters in dictionary with python script

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I made a dictionary in python by retrieving data in json format.

```
[{"id":"1","kingdom":"Metazoa ","phylum":"Arthropoda ","class":"Insecta ","order":"Hemiptera ","family":"Belostomatidae ","genus":"Abedus"},<br>
{"id":"2","kingdom":"Viridiplantae ","phylum":"Streptophyta ","class":"unclassified_Streptophyta ","order":"Pinales ","family":"Pinaceae ","genus":"Abies"}]
```

When I access the data, I am trying to take only the ones in which the value of `genus` is `Abies`, but instead I get the error

> ValueError : invalid literal for int ( ) with base 10 : 'Abies'

But if I input a numeric value, I get data corresponding to the "id" of the json.

This is my script:

```
import urllib2
import simplejson

title = raw_input("find taxonom: ")
print "key: ",title 

response = urllib2.urlopen("http://localhost/csv/taxo.json")
data = simplejson.load(response)
get = int(str(title))
print data[get]
```

How do I get it display data "id", "kingdom", "phlyum", "class", etc of each data that matches the input for genus?

Comment: `int(str(title))` cannot be right: it says "take title, make it a string, and make an integer of this string". I suppose titles are not integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to convert a string containing non numeric values into an integer. To fix that, remove `get = int(str(title))`

---

The data you have is a list. Lists use numeric indexing to access elements at different locations in the list. To print `genus` value, you have to do:

```
print data[1]['genus']
```

Note that this targets the second dictionary in the list. To print the value of `genus` for the first dictionary, you have to change that `1` to `0`

---

To print the value of each dictionary which contains a value for `genus` matching title, do this:

```
for attr_map in data:
    if attr_map['genus'] == title:
        print attr_map
```

Example run of the program:

```
>>> import json
>>> buffer = '[{"id":"1","kingdom":"Metazoa ","phylum":"Arthropoda ","class":"Insecta ","order":"Hemiptera ","family":"Belostomatidae ","genus":"Abedus"},{"id":"2","kingdom":"Viridiplantae ","phylum":"Streptophyta ","class":"unclassified_Streptophyta ","order":"Pinales ","family":"Pinaceae ","genus":"Abies"}]'
>>> data = json.loads(buffer)
>>> data
[{u'kingdom': u'Metazoa ', u'family': u'Belostomatidae ', u'class': u'Insecta ', u'id': u'1', u'phylum': u'Arthropoda ', u'genus': u'Abedus', u'order': u'Hemiptera '}, {u'kingdom': u'Viridiplantae ', u'family': u'Pinaceae ', u'class': u'unclassified_Streptophyta ', u'id': u'2', u'phylum': u'Streptophyta ', u'genus': u'Abies', u'order': u'Pinales '}]
>>>
>>> title = raw_input("find taxonom: ")
find taxonom: Abies
>>> for attr_map in data:
...     if attr_map['genus'] == title:
...         print attr_map
... 
{u'kingdom': u'Viridiplantae ', u'family': u'Pinaceae ', u'class': u'unclassified_Streptophyta ', u'id': u'2', u'phylum': u'Streptophyta ', u'genus': u'Abies', u'order': u'Pinales '}
```

Comment: Probably, not what OP wants. He wants a search by `genus` key.

Comment: thanks @SuperSaiyan, yes I want to find the keywords genus.

Comment: thanks @smac89, if i delete `get = int(str(title))` There is a mistake `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: @dwiyanto remove it and use either the solution I posted or the one from the other answer. The overarching problem is that the data you have is a list and therefore can only be indexed by an integer. Also, the `int` class only accepts strings containing only numeric values

Comment: i try print value no data will appear, can not be read `if attr_map['genus'] == title:`  so result blank

Comment: can help me again  @smac89, I'm Trying to make a statement Condition if_else , but When I add `else:` even appear error `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Comment: @dwiyanto, please ask a different question. The original question you asked has been answered and this is completely unrelated. In answer to your question, make sure you are not mixing tabs with spaces (in fact, use spaces always) and make sure that each level of indentation uses the same number of spaces

Answer (score 2):

This will find the first entry that matches:

```
print next(x for x in data if x["genus"] == title)
```

Comment: If you're going to use `next` and not `[<list comprehension>][0]`, why not just `next(<genexp>)`?

Comment: Forgot to take them off when I wrote `next`. Fixing it now. Thanks for pointing out!